# Open .WQ1 file (Quattro Pro) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am really struggling to find a way to open these Quattro Pro files in excel. I have tried Libre as well. Cannot seem to find something to import these things. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Excel can open Quattro Pro files, but as the file format is old, it makes sense that newer versions of Excel don't support it. In fact, from Microsoft's page on [Excel 2007 supported files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx), `.wq1` isn't supported.

I can tell that it is supported on earlier version of Excel (with [some support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/opening-quattro-pro-files-in-excel-HA001044873.aspx) in Excel 2000) up to Excel 2003.

I've looked around. OpenOffice seems to have *some* support for Quattro Pro files (although not the one you mentioned). The best solutions I've found seem to be converting the file to Excel's format using either the older versions that supported it or Corel's WordPerfect Office X6 [trial](http://www.corel.com/corel/product/index.jsp?&mapcounter=1&pid=prod4720105), which should open and convert the file.